# Trigger ngChange from custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to get my custom directive to activate a ngChange event in order for the original controller to do something when data has changed in the directive.

my directive looks like this:

```
.directive('spInputCheckbox', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                ngChange: '&'
            },
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: 'true',
            template: '<div><span ng-click="model = !model"><i ng-if="model">X</i></span><input type="checkbox" ng-model="model" ng-change="change(model)" /><span ng-if="title">{{ title }}</span></div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr){
                    scope.title = attr.title
                scope.$watch('ngModel', function(value){
                    if(value){
                        scope.model = scope.ngModel
                    }
                });

                scope.change = function(value){
                    scope.ngModel = scope.model
                    scope.ngChange()
                }
            }
        };
    })
```

and here's how I call it

```
<sp-input-checkbox ng-model="info"
      ng-init="info = false"
      title="click me"
      ng-change="alert(7)" />
```

Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaeltotkorsgaard/L56rdqLp/80/) with the code

Answer (score 0):

Since the change is a click event, you can use `ng-click`. A scope function can be called for `ng-click` event.

`<sp-input-checkbox ng-model="info"
          ng-init="info = false"
          title="click me"
          ng-click="modified()" />`

`$scope.modified = function(){
        alert(7);
      };`

[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/pahan_silva/L490ns68/2/)

Comment: this would get the alert to show. but not fire the ng-change event which I'm looking for

Comment: Yeah. But since it is a checkbox and click is the only change possible, why would you need ng-change event?

Comment: in case it was something else than an checkbox, say an input type="text"

Comment: No and that's what bothering me, I can't get the ng-change to work as it normally would, either for type="text" nor type="checkbox"

Comment: If you're interested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o0cudzyw/2/) is an example which doesn't use `ng-change` or `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe watching the **model** can do what you want to achieve like this

```
scope.$watch('model', function(value){
    if(value){
        scope.ngModel = scope.model
        hasChange = true
    }

    if(hasChange) {
             scope.change()
    }
});
```

see whole code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L56rdqLp/100/)