# How Can I Trigger ngChange Event From a Custom Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This question is similar to this [Trigger ngChange from custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369322/trigger-ngchange-from-custom-directive), but the proposed solutions are not good enough to be considered.

I am using AngularJS 1.4.7. I have a directive defined as:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('myDatePicker', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                dateFormat: '@',
                ngModel: '='
            },
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                $element.datepicker({
                    onSelect: function (dateText) { // it will be something like '7 Apr, 2017'

                        // but I want to display the time as well 
                        dateText += ' 18:26:00 PM'; // for simplicity, let's hard code it

                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                        });

                    },
                    dateFormat: $scope.dateFormat,
                    beforeShowDay: beforeShowDay
                });

                function beforeShowDay(date)
                {
                    return [true, ""];
                }
            }
        };
    }]);

}());
```

It uses jQueryUI's DatePicker. And my HTML markup:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
       name="birthDate"
       my-date-picker 
       date-format="d M, yy" 
       data-ng-model="onesBirthday" 
       ng-change="vm.onBirthDateChange(currentPlayer)"
        />
```

For simplicity sake, I will skip my Ng controller, it doesn't matter.

Well, the onBirthDateChange() handler is triggered after selecting a date from the picker, but the input's value is never be '7 Apr, 2017 18:26:00 PM'. So, I changed onSelect() method to read as:

```
onSelect: function (dateText) { // it will be something like '7 Apr, 2017'

    // but I want to display the time as well 
    dateText += ' 18:26:00 PM'; // for simplicity, let's hard code it

    ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = dateText;
    ngModelCtrl.$render();

    $scope.ngModel = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue = dateText;

    $element.change();

}
```

It does change the value of the input control as what I expect, however, the ngChange is never triggered, onBirthDateChange() never runs.

What do I miss? Thanks.

**Background:**

The reason $setViewValue(dateText) doesn't change the view's value to be dateText could be that it fails some internal validation, coz DatePicker doesn't have time part, and the passed string has.